# How may I left-align the following array?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would not like it to be centred.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[a^{'}_{ij}=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
a_{ij}&\: \text{($i\neq r$;\: $i\neq s$)}\\
a_{sj}&\: \text{($i=r$)}\\
a_{rj}&\: \text{($i=s$)}
\end{array}\right.\]\\
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `cases`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[a^{'}_{ij}=\begin{cases}
a_{ij}& (i\neq r;\quad i\neq s)\\
a_{sj}& (i=r)\\
a_{rj}& (i=s)
\end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or do you mean this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,showframe}  %% Remove showframe

\begin{document}
\noindent
$\displaystyle
a^{'}_{ij}=\begin{cases}
a_{ij}& (i\neq r; \quad i\neq s)\\
a_{sj}& (i=r)\\
a_{rj}& (i=s)
\end{cases}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If it is latter, you may also use `flalign*`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,showframe}  %% Remove showframe

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{flalign*}
&a^{'}_{ij}=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
a_{ij}& (i\neq r; \quad i\neq s)\\
a_{sj}& (i=r)\\
a_{rj}& (i=s)
\end{array}\right.&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! You provide the precise answer I looked for. 
Thank you so very much, Harish! 
I think this is the second time, you have provided me an answer. 
Are you on Facebook? :)

Comment: @Harish Kumar: What's the use of the `\text` commands since they contain only maths?

Comment: @Bernard - It looks like it's a holdover from the OP's code that didn't get simplified/streamlined. I agree that the `\text` wrappers and the interior `$` directives should be omitted.

Comment: @Bernard No use. I was too sleepy!. Now cleaned. Thanks.

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa Yes , I am. Search for harish kumar holla